# Is this the simplest way to create const / non const class?

Tags: c++, templates

I wanted to do a class that works similarly to an array.

However most of my pointers were const, and I had problems even if I use `MyArray<const int>`.

This is why i "separated" const and non const class.

However I feel all code inside `my_array_impl_` namespace is bit redundant.

Is there easier way to achieve the same with less code? Thanks

```
    namespace my_array_impl_{

        template<typename T, bool b>
        struct TFactory;

        template<typename T>
        struct TFactory<T, false>{
            using type  = const T;
            using type_void = const void *;
        };

        template<typename T>
        struct TFactory<T, true>{
            using type  = T;
            using type_void = void *;
        };

    }

    template<typename T_, bool M_ = false>
    class MyArray{
        using MyTFactory    = my_array_impl_::TFactory<T_, M_>;

        using T         = typename MyTFactory::type;
        using Void      = typename MyTFactory::type_void;

        T   *ptr_;
        size_t  size_;

    public:
        constexpr MyArray(Void ptr, size_t size) :
                ptr_    (reinterpret_cast<T *>(ptr) ),
                size_   (size / sizeof(T)           ){}

        explicit
        constexpr MyArray(std::string_view s) :
                MyArray(s.data(), s.size()){}

    public:
        constexpr size_t size() const{
            return size_;
        }

        constexpr const auto&operator[](size_t i) const{
            return ptr_[i];
        }

        constexpr auto&operator[](size_t i){
            return ptr_[i];
        }
    };

    template<typename T>
    using MyArrayMutable = MyArray<T, true>;
```

Comment: i dont really understand what problem `MyFactory` solves, but maybe you are looking for [`std::conditional`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/conditional) and [`std::is_const`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_const)

Comment: Presumably you're doing this for a reason but the simplest way to do this would be `std::vector`. In general `const` member variables should be avoided

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number std::conditional it is. Thanks!

Comment: the simpler way is to use `const MyArray<T>` and `MyArray<T>`. `some_container<const T>` is rarely what you actually need and often simply doesnt work (also with standard containers)

Comment: "I wanted to do a class that works similarly to an array." - why not just use what already exists? Like [std::array](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) or [std::vector](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number  const MyArray<T>  still need non const pointer for the c-tor.

Comment: @JesperJuhl my class is more like C++20 std::span

Comment: @Nick I dont understand what you say. I dont see any const pointer in your `MyArray<T>`

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number yes, this means you can not construct the class with const pointer (for example `const int *`. and if you do MyArray<const int>, then it break some other code of mine

Answer (score 1):

All code can be simplified with `std::conditional`:

```
        template<typename T>
        using TFactory      = std::conditional_t<Mutable, T, const T>;

        using T         = TFactory<T_       >;
        using Void      = TFactory<void *   >;
```